# Detach then Append Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, detach

I have been working with this script and its mind boggling as it looks as though it should work correctly, however it is not. So I turn to you all for an extra set of eyes on what I am missing.

Situation: Basically, what I am trying to do is on click detach a div, then when another radio button is selected, append the div back to its position.

I have included a JSFiddle so you can see that I may not be entirely off track : http://jsfiddle.net/heykate/pusk6ezx/

On load, the user is presented with two options, Support or Inflatable with the default size selected on the support size with the other models sizes hidden. Which is fine. I know ultimately I want to change that first line of code from hide() to detach().

Once I go to click on the second style option, it shows the second models widths like it is supposed to, however if I was to switch back to the first style option. The div I originally detached, is still hidden and will not .append() within my code.

Here is what my script looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#5e8a1520d82ed2834919fda63f4a3f84').hide();            
    $('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
             if($(this).attr("value")=="489"){
                $( "#b6304c97422f08727702021e2c6c7cda" ).append( ".rightCol" );
                $("#5e8a1520d82ed2834919fda63f4a3f84").detach();                
              }
             if($(this).attr("value")=="488"){
                $("#b6304c97422f08727702021e2c6c7cda").detach();
                $("#5e8a1520d82ed2834919fda63f4a3f84").show();
            }
        });    
    });
```

Please let me know what I am missing. Basically the reason I am doing this to begin with is

1. To make it less confusing on the front end and
2. because the defaults are set (for both sizes) they get mashed up in the product order info, so if I could clear the other widths checked radio button or detach and prevent it from being seen, I think it would work out just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.detach` REMOVES the element from the DOM. Since it's no longer in the DOM, when you try to `.show()` it later, it's no longer in the dom, and therefore not findable/usable. That's why .detach() returns the node you've removed, in case you want to re-use it:

```
foo = $('#blahblah').detach(); // 'foo' now contains the detached now

$('#otherplace').attach(foo);  // reinsert the foo element we detached.
        //OR
$('#otherplace').append(foo);
```

Comment: Since foo = a detach wouldnt attach just negate it out and it still would render as a detached item?

Comment: yeah, if you ran this exact code. I don't know why you're doing detach. why not just `.hide()` the element you don't want visible? detach modifies the DOM tree and physically cuts stuff out of it.

Comment: I originally had it set up to just hide which is implemented on our page now, but the radio button for the hidden div is pre selected, so its combining with the selection that was visible. if that makes sense.

Comment: gotcha. but regardless, you're modifying the tree by physically removing ("pruning"). Once you've pruned a branch of the tree, it's no longer part of the tree, and since you're not capturing the return value of `.detach()`, the branch you prune is lost and garbage collected.

Comment: `$()` works on the current live dom tree. if you have `$('#foo').detach(), $('#foo').something_else()`, the something else call will fail, because the live dom tree no longer has a #foo element in it.

Comment: So, if I detach something, then there is no way for me to bring it back then? I am sorry for all the questions, but I do appreciate the feedback. My question then is, is there a way the to say foo = this div without a detach or hide to it, then call it as I want within the script? Or that may cause problems on the click back/between the options,hmmm..perplexed.

Comment: that's what I showed you in my code snippet. capture the detached element: `var detached_thing = $('#foo').detach()`, and then you can `.append(detached_thing)` into the tree again, just append it to whatever #foo's parent was originally.

Comment: OMG, i am so sorry Marc! I was wondering why it wasnt working and I wasnt using append....Holy Blonde Moment! Thanks for all your help and I do get it now! Thanks so much for the help!